# Get all matching items using ids array form database

Tags: mongodb, http, angular, express, typescript

I can't receive list of items that matches with my array of ids.

This is PART of code in Angular component:

```
this.orderService.getSpecyficOrders(ids)
    .subscribe(orders => { ...
```

Where ids is an array of

```
[{_id : ID },{_id : ID },{_id : ID },]
```

ID is `"5235sd23424asd234223sf44"` kind of string form MongoDB documents.

In angular service file I have imported:
Http, Headers, and import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Here is code in service in Angular:

```
getSpecyficOrders(ids){
    return this.http.get('/api/ordersspecyfic', ids)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

In express file I have require: multer, express,router,mongojs, db

And here is part of code in express, call to mongodb:

```
router.get('/ordersspecyfic', function(req, res, next){
    var ids = req.body;
    ids = ids.map(function (obj){ return mongojs.ObjectId(obj._id)});
    db.orders.find({_id: {$in: ids}}, function(err, orders){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(orders);
    });
});
```

And I'm getting error:

> Uncaught Response {_body: "TypeError: ids.map is not a function
>     &n…/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)↵", status:
>   500, ok: false, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers:
>   Headers…}

Console.log in express file
is showing me that req.body is an empty object {}

As far as I know `req.body` is not an array,  but I don't know if this is only problem with that code.

All others request of get single element, get all items etc. are working fine.
I just can't get this one working..

Comment: .map() is a prototype of array. If ids is not an array of course you will get that error. `console.log(ids);` to see what is it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: It is empty object {}

But if I'm sending ids in service as JSON.stringify(ids) I'm getting error as well.
Also when I'm using 
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
and , {headers} after ids in request

Comment: If you JSON.stringify(ids) it will be a string, so you can't `.map()` it. If it's an empty object you can do a empty object check to not map it for no reason.

Comment: Indeed, and that is my concern how to send this array from service to express file into req.body properly so I could get list of items based on that array of ids.

Comment: HTTP GET-Method has no `body`!!

Comment: @KrzysztofSkorupski can't set get requests like that, have to set them as part of the url. You can go angular route and use URLSearchParams, but it's much simpler to just create the url yourself: `const url = '/api/ordersspecific?' + ids.map(id => 'ids=' + id._id + '&');`

Comment: And then read with `req.query.ids` on node side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to send `ids` to your server side with

```
return this.http.get('/api/ordersspecyfic', ids)
```

but `http.get` api doesn't work like that

> get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable

In order to send this data to your back-end you should use the post api

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post('/api/ordersspecyfic', ids, options)
```

> post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable

Source:https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html

Comment: @KrzysztofSkorupski glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Two errors, backend and frontend.

1. Frontend error

You say `this.http.get('/api/ordersspecific', ids);`. This does nothing - or specifically, this only tries to get `/api/ordersspecific`. It doesn't send ids, your second parameter doesn't match any [RequestOptions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html). In other words, your ids are ignored.

You'd want to append this as a query string. Check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#search-parameters) how to add querystring parameters. But in short, it'd be something simple like:

```
return this.http.get('/api/ordersspecyfic?ids=<id1>&ids=<id2>...'
```

2. Backend error

You're reading stuff from body. It's a GET request, there should be no body. Read this from querystring:

```
router.get('/ordersspecyfic', function(req, res, next){
  var ids = req.query.ids;
});
```